# Retrieving Random Piece of Code Using PHP

Tags: php

Suppose i have a php file named **main.php**
It Contains following code

```
include 'config.php';
echo $random;
```

And **config.php** File will have many random values

```
43424523422
42342342342
```

Now i need to retrieve any one value from **config.php** to **main.php**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does `config.php` just contain a plain text list of values? How are they stored in `config.php?`

Comment: If you `config.php` just contains raw numbers, it's not a PHP file so you should probably rename it to `config.dat` or something to avoid confusion. In addition, have you actually tried anything yourself?

Comment: This code sounds like it would just print out a webpage with a lot of numbers, as it is right now.

Comment: Also, just how many random values? Tens? Thousands? Millions? It makes a difference in how the file would be accessed and chosen from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can something like this in config.php

```
 $randoms = array("43424523422","42342342342");
```

and in you main.php get random like

```
 echo $randoms[array_rand($randoms)];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One would be to load the file into an array, where each line of the file is converted into one item in the array. The `file()` function will handle this for you:

```
$lines = file("myLines.php");
```

Next you'd want to grab a random entry from that array. You could do that several different ways as well. You could shuffle the array, and shift the first value off, or you could generate a number between 0 and the size of the array (minus one for zero-based index):

```
$randLine = array_rand($lines, 1);
```

The `array_rand()` function takes two arguments: the source array, and the number of random results you would like returned.

Ultimately, `$randLine` contains a random line from your source `myLines.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be read the file into an array then select a random element from the array.

```
$values = file("config.php", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$your_value = array_rand($values,1);
```